# No default constructor when adding servlet filter in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I read [this other posting about how to add a servlet filter in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151057/add-a-servlet-filter-in-a-spring-boot-application), but I am getting a `No Default Constructor` error when I try to follow its example of adding an inner `WebConfig` class within the `UiApplication.java` class file.

I am trying this because adding `ignoring(/api-url` to the app's `SecurityConfig` class caused a message stating the `/api-url has an empty filter list`.  I want to add a servlet filter for `/api-url` so that its filter list is no longer empty.

The code for the `WebConfig` inner class is:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/api-url");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below to enable the servlet filter to be added to `/api-url` without throwing the error?**

The complete code for the UiApplication.java class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class UiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig {

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
            registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
            registration.addUrlPatterns("/api-url");
            return registration;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
            webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/api-url");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/secure**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();;
        }
    }
}
```

And the complete stack trace of the error when I try to launch the Spring Boot jar is:

```
2016-04-10 10:32:58.759 ERROR 5174 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at demo.UiApplication.main(UiApplication.java:193) [modular-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [modular-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:452) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:167) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demo.UiApplication$WebConfig': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:232) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:77) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:235) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:207) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at demo.UiApplication.main(UiApplication.java:193)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demo.UiApplication$WebConfig': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:77)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:235)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: demo.UiApplication$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f410234e.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 34 more
[root@localhost CustomLogin2]#
```

Comment: Make `WebConfig ` static...

Comment: Which version of SpringBoot are you using?

Comment: @Hareesh I am using version 1.3 of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 4):

Make your `WebConfig` class static:

```
@Configuration
public static class WebConfig { ... }
```

Also, do not put all of your configurations in one class, try to put them in separate classes.

Comment: Thank you and +1.  Adding the word `static` where you indicated has resulted in the app compiling.  But that is half of the OP's question.  How can I resolve the second half of the OP, which would confirm that the `/api-url` does indeed have a filter attached to it now?

Comment: Send a request to one of endpoints that starts with `api-url` with appropriate etag header and put a breakpoint in `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter#doFilterInternal`.

Comment: Thank you.  What do you mean by "appropriate etag header?"  I have sent a request for `/api-url` and the result is the debug logs printing `/api-url has an empty filter list`.  The actual url is `/registration-form`, but I am using the term `/api-url` in this OP to keep things generic so others can use it too.

Comment: Also, I looked in `UiApplication.java` and there is no `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter#doFilterInternal`, so I am not sure where to put the break point.

Comment: `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` has a method called `doFilterInteral`.

Comment: I am looking through the eclipse maven dependencies for the project to try to find the right jar containing `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter`.  Any idea which jar contains it?  The package is `org.springframework.web.filter.`.

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + T` then type the class name to search for class by name in eclipse

Comment: Your configuration looks fine and the filter should be registered. That debug message is for spring security, since you've ignored the `api-url`.

Comment: I put break points at every line inside `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal()`, and then I made another request to `/api-url` from a front-end app in a different server container, but the Spring Boot debug log still says that `/api-url has an empty filter chain`, and **the break points never stopped the program's control flow**.

Comment: Check your http response, do you see `ETag` header in response headers?

Comment: The `Network tab` of the Firefox Developer Tools gives a 403 error, and the `raw headers` section for the `response` gives the following:  `Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH  
Content-Length: 20  
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 19:41:48 GMT  
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1  
X-Application-Context: application:8001`

Comment: Spring security blocked the request! Are you sure you're sending the request to `/api-url`?

Comment: Yes, the request is definitely going to `/api-url`.  This whole problem emerged when I moved my AngularJS code outside the Spring Boot jar/app and into a separate Node.js container.  Spring security started blocking the anonymous calls to api end points.  I have tried many things to simply open up the public end points.  Manually adding the servlet filter is the most recent attempt to overcome the `/api-url has an empty filter list` message that happens whenever a supposedly public api end point is called from the outside app.

Comment: IMO ask another question for the second part of your question and add more details about project structure

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  Lemme ponder how to deal with this question.  In the meantime, if you are interested in the broader question, this is actually the tangent/sidebar question to the broader question.  The project structure is simple enough that I might resort to minimizing it enough to post a zip of an entire reproduceable project.  Here is the link to the larger question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489253/api-url-has-an-empty-filter-list-in-spring-boot-security

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below two question which have similar question,

Answer by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831855/nosuchmethodexception-thrown-by-annotationvalidationinterceptor-when-executing-an-action)

and a issues at [Spring-Project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/382)